# How do I get CSS styling on navigation through included php script?

Tags: php, html, css, header, navigation

I am building a website that uses includes php scripts.

I've got a header.php file, where it contains the logo, and the navigation, and a footer.php file that contains information. These are loaded from the main content files, for example, from the home page, I have a `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>` script.

The main problem I am having is the navigation. Because it is included in the header, none of the formatting is working as it should, so when I click on a page, the CSS styling doesn't change so the user knows what page they are on. From what I am gathering, the header.php file is refreshing the information.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Examples of code or images of the behavior you are seeing and what you are expecting is a good start aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Including the `header.php` file won't affect this as the CSS is processed on the client side.

What you need to do is have make your header.php file aware of which page it is on so it can assign a class to the navigation element appropriate to that page. Then make sure you have a rule in your CSS that specifically states that any navigation element that has that class will be highlighted appropriately.

A *rough* example:

**page.php**

```
$current_page = 'home';
include('header.php');
```

**header.php**

```
<ul>
  <li<?php if ($current_page === 'home') echo ' class="highlight"'?>><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li<?php if ($current_page === 'about') echo ' class="highlight"'?>><a href="/">About</a></li>
</ul>
```